# Regarding iOS resolution support for cocos2d-JS v3 portrait mode

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I have an assets made with 1920 * 1080 resolution , with the same resolution I want to support iOS how with the scaling factor without getting new assets. It is working properly in android but not in iOS

I was trying the multiresolution support provided by cocos2d-x but then Its not working properly,
Here what I was trying

```
cc.view.setDesignResolutionSize(1080,1920, cc.ResolutionPolicy.FIXED_HEIGHT);
```

Its showing very small view port at the top right corner and I am unable to understand why this is happening and how do I solve this.

Comment: Try to swap the width and height in the setDesignResolutionSize? And it's not good a idea to use a very big design resolution size

Comment: Can you show us result screen ?

Comment: @Emadpres : Thanks but I resolved it by myself,I created new project with portrait mode , and now everything works fine , there was surely some issue regarding landscape setttings